# Is there a possibility to make the grey word "Information" not appear when the form "form" is called by form[]?

Tags: interface, user-interface

Is there a possibility to make the grey word "Information" not appear when the form "form" is called by form[]?

```
Clear[form];
form = FormFunction[
   "Information" ->
    RepeatingElement[
    CompoundElement[
      <|
       {"Property", Style["Property", 16, Black, Bold]} -> 
        "String",
       {"Unit", Style["Unit", 16, Black, Bold]} -> "String"
       |>
      ]
     ],
    AppearanceRules ->
    <|
     "Title" -> " ",
     "Description" -> 
     Column[{Style["Enter your information", Bold, 20, Red]}]
     |>
   ];
form[]
```

Thank you beforehand for answers.

Regards.

Gianni Mocellin

Comment: You could always replace `"Information"` with `"\[InvisibleSpace]"`

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2440929).

Comment: Thank you, Rohit.

Comment: By the way, Bill, I am a user of Mathematica since Version 1.0 and what I am trying to do is to emulate with Mathematica something that was running very well in Lisp into a Mac with the little interface possibilities of it's interface which was still in an EPROM in... 1985.

Comment: There is this from the documentation: `FormObject[{
  "First" -> <|"Label" -> None, "Hint" -> "First Name"|>,
  "Last" -> <|"Label" -> None, "Hint" -> "Last Name"|>
  }]`  and I think FormFunction will take a FormObject as its first argument.  Perhaps this may help, Not sure.